# Deploying to multiple Firebase Hosting sites in multiple projects

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have 2 Firebase projects (production and testing) and I'm logged into them in Firebase CLI. I switch between them by calling `firebase use testing` etc.

I also have a simple hosting project in a `hosting` directory.

I created 2 sites:

- `join` in `production`
- `join-tst` in `testing`

How can I setup my project so that I can deploy the same hosting to both sites? My current `firebase.json` is as follows now.

```json
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "site": "join-tst",
      "public": "hosting",
      "cleanUrls": true,
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "redirects": [
        {
          "source": "/",
          "destination": "https://mywebsite.com/",
          "type": 301
        }
      ],
      "headers": [
        {
          "source": "/.well-known/*",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Content-Type",
              "value": "application/json"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I cannot replicate the same experience with hosting as I have with cloud functions. For cloud functions I just need to switch environment and then call

```bash
firebase use testing
firebase deploy --only functions
```

Can I achieve something like this and don't worry about the site names:

```bash
firebase use testing
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve that by assigning the same target name to both sites in both projects:

```bash
firebase use testing
firebase target:apply hosting your-target-name join-tst
firebase use production
firebase target:apply hosting your-target-name join
```

Then the `firebase.json` needs to be just:

```json
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "your-target-name",
      "public": "hosting"
      ...
    }
  ]
```

Comment: can you help me out with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77163103/firebase-deploying-multiple-sites-to-different-environmentsprojects